# Mount points created with udev rule not visible

Tags: server, mount, 20.04, automount, udev

I'm using Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (upgraded from 18.04) and have the following udev rule installed:

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/bash /usr/local/bin/media_hotplug.sh"
```

The script contains:

```
LOG="/var/log/media_hotplug.log"
date >> $LOG
pmount /dev/disk/by-uuid/e5b2c0da-e044-4e5a-b2e9-139322322b71 backup >> $LOG
ls -la /media/backup >> $LOG
echo done >> $LOG
```

I can see that the script is executed correctly, it lists the directories of my external usb drive to my log file:

```
Mon Jun  1 10:44:11 CEST 2020
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 18  2017 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jun  1 10:37 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 root root 4096 Mar 28  2018 Media
done
```

But the mount point is never visible to users, even root cannot access it. `mountpoint /media/backup` says there is no mount point and `ls -la /media/backup` just shows an empty file named `.created_by_pmount`. If I instead use `mount -a` in the script and adjust `/etc/fstab` accordingly, the same thing happens.

It's like the `udev` script is executed in its own environment where mount points are not exported or something like this. Every tutorial regarding `udev` and automount is not working on my machine and google finds nothing about hidden mount points when using `udev` rules.

Everything worked in Ubuntu 18.04, but 20.04 seems to do things differently. What is happening? What can I do?

Comment: That is exactly what is happening, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330094/udev-rule-to-mount-disk-does-not-work

Comment: @Martin yes, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: I stand corrected, I also had to follow this advice: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535629/usbmount-not-working-with-mountflags-shared-on-newer-kernel and adding PrivateMounts=no to the config file.